# Clean properties for specifc tags in HTML

Tags: python, html, string

Hello I would like to clean an HTML. More clearly I want to convert this:

```html
<a href="https://example.com" class="image image-thumbnail">
    <img
        src="https://example.com"
        alt="abc" 
        class="lzy lzyPlcHld " 
        data-image-key="abc.png"
        data-image-name="abc.png"
        data-src="https://example.com/x.jpg"
        width="70"
        height="52"
        onload="if(typeof lazy==='object'){lazy.load(this)}">
</a>
```

into this:

```html
    <a href="https://example.com">
        <img src="https://example.com/x.jpg" alt="abc">
    </a>
```

Any suggestions? regex maybe? or there is another tool or framework in Python that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to clean this tag using regex. In this example, I will use two conditions to clean this HTML up.

#### Condition 1

```
(?<=[^>])(\s+)(?=\s\w)
```

This condition selects all of the characters that come after a closing `>` and the spaces that come after it. This helps to remove the line breaks in the cleaned HTML.

#### Condition 2

```
(\s(class|data|width|height|onload)=[^<>]+)
```

This condition selects the all of tags that are undesired. However, there are a few conditions that still have to be met so only tags are removed and not other text that may contain, for example, "class," "data," etc. The `\s` denotes that the tags must be preceded by a space and the `=[^<>]+` denotes that the tags must be followed by `=` and all text that are not open `<` or `>`.

#### Conclusion

When joining these two halves, don't forget to join them with the `|` operator so that we can grab all characters that meet either one of the two conditions above and use `re.sub` to replace them with nothing.

The final script looks like this:

```
regexp = r'(?<=[^>])(\s+)(?=\s\w)|\s(class|data|width|height|onload)=[^<>]+'
pattern = re.compile(regexp)
cleaned = re.sub(pattern, '', html)
```

Output:

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
    <img src="https://example.com" alt="abc">
</a>
```

Comment: Updated to `r'(?<=[^>])(\s+)(?=\s\w)|\s(class|data|width|height|onload)=".+?"'`